# Is there any way to represent ~27 integers in a bitset and access them efficiently?

Tags: c

I have a struct with an array of 27 signed integers. This struct takes about 112 bytes of memory after packing bytes. I would like to reduce the size of the struct. Since these ints cannot be greater than 400k I only need 20 bits to represent them. I'm wasting a decent amount of memory since I need to have many such structs. Is there any way I could reduce the memory cost while still being able to access each int without too much of a performance loss? Is implementing a bitset the best way to go?

Comment: How would you need to access those 20bit values? All at once, or randomly only one, or ...

Comment: 19 bits are enough for values up to just under 524288, just saying ...

Comment: @pmg I need the extra bit for representing the sign, don't I?

Comment: @alk I need to be able to retrieve the original int somehow. Accessing 20 bits at a time is probably faster

Comment: If you´re using negative numbers, yes, sorry, my bad. If your values go from `0` to `400k` you can ignore sign bit :)

Comment: @SanathJathanna - it will not be any "faster" than accessing a normal 32-bit integer as the size of an integer matches the native CPU register size. You will need an additional offset or shift & mask to actually reach and isolate your number.

Comment: How often do you need to access the single values?

Comment: Why don’t you try writing code to extract 3 byte/24-bit values from your byte array of 27*3 bytes, to see if that is not too much of a performance loss for you?

Comment: Why is the memory an issue?

What are you programming for?

These things are important too. But I think it's important to mention that no matter what you do, not just in C, in any programming problem, you cannot have both. You either sacrifice memory usage, or speed. The way you have written it, focuses on speed and somewhat is aware of memory problem, you said you're using ints, not longs (assuming they're bigger than int), for example. Anything using less memory ***will*** have performance impact.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I'm not looking for faster performance while accessing the int. It should compress the size of my struct. The additional operations needed to access the int should be compensated for by the reduction in size

Comment: @alk Many times. About the order of a million or so times

Comment: @barny Yeah, that seems to be the easiest way to implement this

Comment: @Sahsahae Basically I'm building a trie. Compressing the size of the structs had pretty good performance benefits. I can always go back to my current version if the size reduction doesn't compensate for the speed cost

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is called *bit-packing*, although a bitset is probably not the right way to phrase it. A bitset, at least in C++ and Java, takes up more space than the bits of data, which defeats your purpose.

Instead, in C you can use *bit-fields* or do the bit fiddling yourself. Bit-fields are elements in structures that have a specified size in bits. They are specifically designed to allow space saving. But in your case there are two issues with this approach:

1. Given your fields are relatively large (20 bits), they might not pack as well as you'd like. A few choices associated with word boundaries are [implementation defined](http://www.catb.org/esr/structure-packing/), so you might find the compiler ends up wasting too much space anyway.
2. bit-fields don't allow the use of arrays, so specifying 27 individual fields might be cumbersome.

So I'd recommend doing it yourself. Simply declare your array to be a 27*20/8 (rounded up) byte array:

```
#define ROUND_UP(n,d) (((n) + (d) - 1) / (d));
unsigned char myPackedIntArray[ROUND_UP(27*20,8)];
```

Then write a getter and a setter:

```
int unpack(unsigned char packedArray[], int index)
{
  struct {signed int i:20;} res; //handy way to do the sign extension from 20 bits to int width.
  int byteIndex = index*20 / 8;
  if(index%2 == 0) //even 20-bit fields start on a byte boundary
  {
    res.s =  (packedArray[byteIndex  ]<<12);
    res.s += (packedArray[byteIndex+1]<<4);
    res.s += (packedArray[byteIndex+2]>>4);
  }
  else //odd 20-bit fields start halfway through the byte
  {
    res.s =  ((packedArray[byteIndex  ]&0x0F) << 16);
    res.s += ((packedArray[byteIndex+1]     ) << 8);
    res.s += ((packedArray[byteIndex+2]     );
  }

  return (int)(res.s);
}

int pack(unsigned char packedArray[], int index)
{
  //left as exercise to the reader
}
```

to pack and unpack 20-bit values into a tightly packed array.

Now to the question of performance - looking at the getter and setter gives you a good idea. Instead of one fetch, there'll be roughly one multiplication and division, 3 fetches and a few bit operations. [Dan Lemire](https://lemire.me/blog/2012/03/06/how-fast-is-bit-packing/) has some excellent results on the topic. The short answer is "not much worse", but ultimately it's going to have a lot to do with your compiler and your architecture.